Where do I find energy drinks?
In The Slums in Stray, there are robots who want energy drinks. I can't find them. How many energy drinks are there and how do I find them?

There are 4 of them:

It can be found very close to where you regain control in The Slums. When facing the garage next to the Guardian with the meditating robots inside, go left down the stairs past the gardener to the area near the entrance to the sewers. Opposite Morusque the musician you'll find a pair of vending machines, so approach the green one that's lit up.

This is in the area where you first entered The Slums, and a robot closed a gate up some side steps off the initial alleyway to keep you out. Head back to this spot, which can also be found by starting at the Super Spirit Laundry – have a Stray Scratch on the front door while you're here – then going down the yellow-lit alley ahead until you reach the end.

Find the narrow alleyway between Super Spirit Laundry and Grandma Clothing where a robot named Rozey is sat watching TV at the bottom of some steps. Climb up to the balcony directly above them, where a yellow vending machine sits to provide another energy drink can.

Start from Grandma Clothing and jump up the AC units on the corner opposite to reach the rooftop where a robot named Heptor is sat. Diagonally opposite from here is another rooftop with an orange vending machine on it, which will give you the last energy drink can.


More info here, with some useful screenshots.
